# Библиотека InputSimulator в игре

Tags: c#, winforms

В игру не передает нажатие клавиш, несмотря на то, что окно активно.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IntPtr DialogHandle = FindWindow(null, "окно игры");
    if (DialogHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Window is not running.");
        return;
    }

    SetForegroundWindow(DialogHandle);

    InputSimulator sim = new InputSimulator();
    sim.Keyboard.KeyPress((VirtualKeyCode)0x28);
}
```

Воспользовавшись поиском, я понял что это из-за защиты в самой игре, но углубившись в эту проблему, многие ссылаются на то, что `SendInput` - прекрасно справляется с заданной задачей, а в этой библиотеке как раз он и используется, но увы, не работает :(

Подтолкните, пожалуйста, на путь истинный.

Comment: Что за игра? Выполните в командной строке Visual Studio `dumpbin "путь к exe-файлу игры" /imports`  и покажите результат

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, игра Pro Evolution Soccer 2017. Командная строка Visual Studio это "Средства" -> "Внешние инструменты..."? В поле `команда` указываю игру, в `аргументы` пишу `dumpbin "C:\Games\Pro Evolution Soccer 2017\PES2017.exe" /imports`, на выходе - ошибка.

Comment: `Пуск - Все программы - Visual Studio - Командная строка разработчика.` Вообще, могу сказать что для современной серьезной игры маловероятно организовать имитацию ввода такими простыми способами. Дело даже не в защите, если игра использует DirectInput/RawInput в эксклюзивном режиме, средствами WinAPi на ее ввод никак не повлиять.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, dumpbin не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемый программой или пакетным файлом

Comment: Видимо у вас не установлена та часть студии, с которой поставляется эта утилита. Вы можете скачать любую утилиту для просмотра зависимостей, типа Dependency Walker, чтобы посмотреть библиотеки, которые использует игра.Если там будет что-то вроде dinput.dll, способ с SendInput не будет работать.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, `DINPUT8.DLL`. Спасибо за помощь.